# Strange net paths in WHOIS

Tags: c++, network-programming, network-protocols, whois

As a self-learning project, I'm implementing a C++ whois client.  I'm using a couple of ancient C implementations for reference, e.g. [koders.com](http://www.koders.com/c/fid72A4233245F5DF6BBFBD94A3CDE86CE61457FC56.aspx?s=split).

One thing puzzles me.  As well as the expected path format, like example.com, example.co.uk, 192.0.32.10 or 2620:0:2d0:200::10, the old C implementations accept some other formats:

1. Paths beginning with one of the following strings:
   "net-", "netblk-", "asn-", "as-", "lim-", "coco-",  "coho-" or "core-".

I presume these look something like "netblk-example" but I don't have a working example.

1. Paths ending in one of the following strings:
   "-au-dom", "-dom",  "-org", "-hst", "-arin", "-ripe", "-mnt", "-gandi", "-ap", "-au", "-ti", "-is", "-6bone", "-norid", "-ripn", "-sgnic", "-metu", "-cknic" or "-kg".

Again, I presume these look like "example-arin" but I'm not certain.

To (finally) get to my question: does anybody know what these paths are?  Are they still used?  Does anybody have legit examples of valid paths like these?

**Update 23 May 2011**
Added C++ tag (my implementation language) as nobody seems to even view "network-programming" without a language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These extra strings are (mostly) for recognising the object types maintained by the *Regional Internet Registries*, such as RIPE, ARIN, APNIC.

Their databases are also accessible via the `whois` protocol, even though the entries within them are not domain names.

Comment: I had guessed that much, but I want to know if they are still in use and preferably some real-life examples that I can use in testing.

Comment: after more research, I now think I understand, and realise your answer is better than I originally thought.